# User not authorized to perform iam:GetRole error while creating Genomics Virtual Lab (GVL) for AWS using CloudMan

Tags: amazon-web-services, galaxy

I'm getting following error while trying to create a new appliance in AWS.

```
FAILURE Create appliance task failed: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/<user> is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role genomics-virtual-lab-20-03-11t18-29-cm2-kube-role
```

It seems I need to add GetRole to may user in AWS console. But I am a newbie to AWS and can't do that. Can anyone please help me?

Regards,

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Try adding another permission - AdministratorAccess - to your IAM user

Comment: In my case i add AdministratorAccess-Amplify for amplify app...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is generally a bad idea. You should only give IAM users the minimum permissions necessary.

Comment: It's not recommended to give root access through the IAM roles. It's highly risky.

Answer (score 10):

try adding below permission.as admin permission should not be added.

```
iam:GetRole
iam:PassRole
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer that is marked as 'correct' is actually incorrect and this is BAD idea, not meeting security practices!
iam:GetRole is the permission that you need to add to your role.